# How to create a powershell-5 module with multiple .psm1 files

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-module

Lest say I have three classes names `Dog`, `Cat` and `Tree` in matching files `Dog_file.psm1`,`Cat_file.psm1` and `Tree_file.psm1`. I need to create one Powershell module with these three files. while I'm reading trough https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337(v=vs.85).aspx I feel it can be achieve.

By reading various post and articles I think `NestedModules` property in the `.psd1` is the way. But not sure exactly how would be the folder structure that files need to place and syntax of the `.psd1` file. So far couldn't find any sample

Someone done this before? I'm using `Powershell 5`

Comment: You can place the *.psm1 files side-by-side with the *.psd1 file in a folder of the same name as the module name

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen: Any idea about the *.psd1 syntax?

Comment: Detailed in the article you linked. Easiest way to get started is by using `New-ModuleManifest`. I would also recommend [this post](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Building-A-PowerShell-Module/)

Comment: Since Warren Frame's material was posted, I'd also recommend his content that he just provided at the PowerShell summit that [he posted on github](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/WritingModules).